# Suppress group_by 0 or any other desired value

Tags: r, group-by

After feedback I pose the problem in another way which I think explains the desired output clearer. I am specifically looking for optimizing computation by reducing the amount of group_by combinations need to be evaluated. I am not able (at least not to my current knowlede) to filter the data prior to performing group by to reach the desired speed up in calculations.

I have the following tribble. I want to group by the combinations created by the crossing below. In order to speed up computation time I want to ignore all the 0 values in the group by function. So it should group by all values except by 0. Filtering after performing the calculations is no option as I want to speed up the calculation in the grouping (which is the part taking hours in my original dataset)

```
df <- tribble(~Size, ~A, ~B, ~D, ~E,
     -10, "4", "0", "1", "1",
     5, "1", "0", "1", "2",
     1, "1", "0", "1", "0",
     1, "2", "1", "3", "3",
     2, "3", "0", "2", "2",
     1, "1", "3", "0", "1",
     3, "3", "2", "2", "1",
     3, "2", "0", "0", "2",
     1, "2", "0", "3", "0",
     1, "0", "2", "2", "0")

Group1 <- c("A","B")
Group2 <- c("D","E")

filtergroups <- crossing(Group1,Group2)
filtergroups <- split(unlist(filtergroups, use.names = FALSE), row(filtergroups))

results = lapply(filtergroups, FUN = function(x) {
do.call(what = group_by_, args = c(list(df), x)) %>%
    summarise( n = length(Size), 
               avgVar1 = mean(Size))
}
)

results <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,results)
```

The result which I get is:

```
results

      A    D n   avgVar1   E    B
1     0    2 1   1.000000 <NA> <NA>
2     1    0 1   1.000000 <NA> <NA>
3     1    1 2   3.000000 <NA> <NA>
4     2    0 1   3.000000 <NA> <NA>
5     2    3 2   1.000000 <NA> <NA>
6     3    2 2   2.500000 <NA> <NA>
7     4    1 1 -10.000000 <NA> <NA>
8     0 <NA> 1   1.000000    0 <NA>
9     1 <NA> 1   1.000000    0 <NA>
10    1 <NA> 1   1.000000    1 <NA>
11    1 <NA> 1   5.000000    2 <NA>
12    2 <NA> 1   1.000000    0 <NA>
13    2 <NA> 1   3.000000    2 <NA>
14    2 <NA> 1   1.000000    3 <NA>
15    3 <NA> 1   3.000000    1 <NA>
16    3 <NA> 1   2.000000    2 <NA>
17    4 <NA> 1 -10.000000    1 <NA>
18 <NA>    0 1   3.000000 <NA>    0
19 <NA>    1 3  -1.333333 <NA>    0
20 <NA>    2 1   2.000000 <NA>    0
21 <NA>    3 1   1.000000 <NA>    0
22 <NA>    3 1   1.000000 <NA>    1
23 <NA>    2 2   2.000000 <NA>    2
24 <NA>    0 1   1.000000 <NA>    3
25 <NA> <NA> 2   1.000000    0    0
26 <NA> <NA> 1 -10.000000    1    0
27 <NA> <NA> 3   3.333333    2    0
28 <NA> <NA> 1   1.000000    3    1
29 <NA> <NA> 1   1.000000    0    2
30 <NA> <NA> 1   3.000000    1    2
31 <NA> <NA> 1   1.000000    1    3
```

What I want to come out directly after group_by is this (it ingnores any group building with 0):

```
      A    D n   avgVar1   E    B
1     1    1 2   3.000000 <NA> <NA>
2     2    3 2   1.000000 <NA> <NA>
3     3    2 2   2.500000 <NA> <NA>
4     4    1 1 -10.000000 <NA> <NA>
5     1 <NA> 1   1.000000    1 <NA>
6     1 <NA> 1   5.000000    2 <NA>
7     2 <NA> 1   3.000000    2 <NA>
8     2 <NA> 1   1.000000    3 <NA>
9     3 <NA> 1   3.000000    1 <NA>
10    3 <NA> 1   2.000000    2 <NA>
11    4 <NA> 1 -10.000000    1 <NA>
12 <NA>    3 1   1.000000 <NA>    1
13 <NA>    2 2   2.000000 <NA>    2
14 <NA> <NA> 1   1.000000    3    1
15 <NA> <NA> 1   3.000000    1    2
16 <NA> <NA> 1   1.000000    1    3
```

Comment: You want to filter out certain values but not using a filter? I think this merits more explanation. What kind of scenario we're talking about? At least adjust the examples as currently the purpose is unclear - you're essentially filtering out rows as shown in your desired output.

Comment: I adapted the question in order to account for the complexity of the problem. Filtering rows prior or after the group_by calculations unfortunately do not help me in my case. Sorry for explaining it unclear. I hope you understand it now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can `filter(!is.na(Group))` first or more generally, filter out anything you do not need for the aggregation before the aggregation happens.

Comment: For the real dataset I cannot do this as I would delete relevant rows (my grouping includes many combinations of different columns). Is there a way to adapt the group_by command?

Comment: @AlexRohrer you will have to update your question with the relevant information. This answer given here is the best option for the posted example

Comment: @AlexRohrer to be honest, your intent is not clear to me. You could try base R aggregate(df$Group, by = list(df$Group), FUN = length) which omits NA values.

Comment: I adapted the question in order to account for the complexity of the problem. Filtering rows prior or after the group_by calculations unfortunately do not help me in my case. Sorry for explaining it unclear. I hope you understand it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still filter for 0s. Please see the updated code.

```
library(tidyverse)

fn <- function(.df, .chr){
  .df %>%
    select("Var1" = .chr[1], "Var2" = .chr[2], Size) %>%
    group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
    filter(Var1 != 0 & Var2 != 0) %>%
    summarise(n = length(Size),
              avgVar1 = mean(Size)) %>% ungroup() %>%
    setNames(c(.chr, c("n", "avgVar1")))
}

filtergroups %>%
  map(~fn(df, .x)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```